# nuxtjs middleware rest API raw data requests

Tags: nuxtjs

I have build nuxtjs example with built in rest API requests with middleware technique. In index.js of my middleware section I put some code :

```
export default {
  handler(req, res) {
    res.write('Everything ok!')
    console.log(req);
    console.log(res);
    res.end()
  },
  path: '/test15'
}
```

When I call http://ip:port/test15/?cmd=somecmd&param=testparam

In console.log I get params data in log, everything nice. No matter which method used, post or get, it also fixed in log.

The problem is when I try to send raw data (ex json) in request body or form data. I can`t see them in any log output.
So question is, is it possible to send some data in such requests via middleware ?

Thanks!

Comment: here is an blog post how to build an REST api with nuxt https://blogxon.com/articles/basic-express-nuxt-api

Answer (score 1):

`middleware` in nuxt is a sandwich for internal routes aka client side. For your question `serverMiddleware` is the answer that work on the server side. You can checkout more [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware/)

Quick example:
In your `nuxt.config.js` file add like below

```
  serverMiddleware: [
    { path: '/api/subscribe', handler: '~/api/subscribe' }
  ],
```

Then create an api folder you can create `subscribe.js` file to add relative api route.

```
import express from 'express'
const app = express()

app.get('/subscribe', async (req, res) => {
    res.send('love to the world');
})

export default {
    path: '/api',
    handler: app
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I don`t fix any data that I send in request body. Difference between middleware and serverMiddleware I have checked. But in my example I can send some data in header with  header-key : JSON, but I think not good idea  transfer in header.

Comment: @Sergey passing `token` in the header is absolutely correct.

Comment: But I want basically pass data in request body... I think it`s more correct way and avoid possible errors.

Comment: @Sergey well, as a matter of good practice `authentication` tokens are meant to be passed in header requests. This way api can be secured more efficiently. Apart from this any data that you pass in json is viable and also correct.

Comment: And no matter of size ?

Comment: @Sergey checkout maximum header size https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-the-maximum-size-of-HTTP-header-values

Comment: So better send in body, but how in nuxtjs ? Header is workaround...  I need send some data in json format, not a token or any auth.